# How to translate “路人缘” or “观众缘” in English

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, traditional-characters, phrase, equivalent-phrase

In this context,

- 缘 = potential relationships, connection
- 路人 = average Joe, random person, total stranger
- 观众 = audience, viewer

路人缘 （路人緣）and 观众缘 (觀眾緣) pretty much means the same thing.
They are used to describe if an actor/character has a feel which naturally appeal the first time viewer/stranger (similar to Love at first sight).

They are like an attribute. So good “观众缘” means this person is popular/in favor.

I crossed out TV friendly from the list, because it means something else.
I thought about congenial feel, affinity for audience, feel which naturally appeal audience..........but nothing sound right

Comment: Are you looking for the word *charming*, *relatable*, or *down-to-earth*?

Comment: Charm would be the word.

Comment: @droooze similar to the suggestion of using "popular". I felt charm is too strong, I would not use charm to describe Baymax, Mr.bean...

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

> After reading my take on the comments, I have convinced myself that 观众缘 means [**audience appeal**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/audience-appeal)

人缘(n) = popularity

路人缘 = **general appeal** /popularity among common folks

观众缘 = **audience appeal** / popularity among viewers/ audience

有人缘 = popular

有观众缘 = popular among viewers/ audience

~

Since there's a lively discussion in the comments section arguing about the definition of 人缘, 观众缘, I would give my two cents here.

缘 is something like a 'fated connection',  The chance of any two people in different parts of the world would meet is extremely tiny, but somehow people from different part of the world do meet. We called this connection between them  有缘.

when we say someone 有人缘, we are saying this person seemingly fated to connect with many many people, in other words, he is popular among people. People seemingly draw to him by fate.

有观众缘 just replace 人缘 with 观众缘, meaning audience seemingly draw to that person with no apparent reason.

We would not say a super star 有观众缘, because he is so good that people love him for his talent, but we often say a new artist or second string performer 有观众缘-- the audience just like him, as if fate decided so

*May be the reason for some audience to like a performer is actually his looks, personality or demeanor. It all seems mysterious to the other audience who can't see anything attractive about the same performer*

Comment: Doesn't really sound right to say xxx looks popular among viewers/ audience. Because popularity sound like a thing developed over a period of time, not a first sight thing.

Comment: unlike 眼缘,  人缘 is not a  first sight thing,  有人缘  just means you are good at making people like you

Comment: Regards of actor/character, there're three groups: 粉丝(fans), 黑子(opposite to fans, ppl who don't like the actor), and 路人(ppl who neither love or hate the actor), so a good 路人缘 means this actor attracts not only 粉丝 but also 路人. I think this answer is quite precise.

Comment: To my understanding, 路人緣 is more like 眼缘 than 人缘。Do you happen to have a word for 眼缘? tks

Comment: 合眼缘  means ' good first impression' e.g. "這女孩很很合我眼缘" ( this girl makes good first impression on me) ; 靠眼缘 means 'depend on the first impression" e.g  "選新車靠眼缘" (choosing a new car depend on the first impression)

Comment: 人缘 is not that "*popularity*" in fact. *popularity* is more on the aspect of *being popular, famous or known by people*. But 人缘 is *one's network or relations with others*, often implying he has certain supportive qualification in his characteristic. Saying 他人缘很好 means *he has a good network or he has good relations with others*, not he is popular. On the other hand, saying 他人缘很好 often implies he has the ability or certain characteristic that can help him to build up a good relationship with others.

Comment: So, for near-synonyms of 'popular' maybe consider well-received, charismatic, crowd-pleaser, wo/man of the people, much loved, personable. OP's "audience appeal" could work in some contexts. I would also like to second drooze's 'charming' and 'relatable' options

Comment: @steveLangsford those words are specific. Xx缘 in Chinese is not that specific. For example, 他有女人缘 means women like him for some reason, which is implied or hard to tell. Or the reason could be he has that kind of luck. That's why I said we might have to interpret differently according to context. We have to learn form the context the speaker put into first. By doing so, we are clear what he is trying to convey, so we can make an appropriate translation.

Comment: Interesting! Could not agree more that context is everything, that's why I think it's useful to brainstorm many options. Your description of the breadth of xx缘 makes me think just "good with xx" might be a nice option sometimes, here "good with an audience" or "good with people". I do think it's going to be very hard to use 'luck' for this, although I see the motivation from 缘, 'lucky with x' might work for 'the ladies' in 女人缘 if you want the risqué connotation but it probably won't work for audiences or people in the street.

Comment: @steveLangsford, so does ''good with people'' mean he has a good network or good relations with others in English? If so, I think it's a pretty good option.

Comment: More that this person has the ability to build good relations easily. Similarly: "good with dogs" or "good with children". Doesn't mean an existing network, implies that encounters with a new dog or child are likely to go well, even if that dog/child is usually not very agreeable.

Comment: @steveLangsford then they are probably different. The Chinese term can imply both. Can you look into those example sentences in my answer to see if they are proper English? I want to know if those translations convey the meanings they intended to mean.

Comment: @steveLangsford can I say:he naturally had a good affinity for common folks/viewers/audience? I like "good" because it is more neutral (v.s popular,charm), but then it is little ambiguous.

Comment: @Hh810674, well, it depends on the context, but I think there are some contexts where this would work, it's an option! Consider also 'affinity with x', or 'rapport with'

Comment: @Tang Ho your latest definition matched what I thought. I'm just not sure if "audience appeal" is the only/best concentrated word choice. Can you put this: 我觉得他有种天生的观众缘 into English? thks

Answer (score 2):

**缘** here means ***an ability or qualification to build up a good relationship***. **观众缘** can be ***an ability or qualification to build up a good relationship with the audience***.

I don't know if you can find a fixed English equivalent for them. So, the interpretation could be various according to the context.

For example,

> 她很有观众缘 // she is a very attractive woman to the audience.
>
> 他有路人缘 // he is attractive to strangers.
>
> 他观众缘很差 // he has no luck to gain the favor of his audience.

Comment: I feel like attractive is too strong. Say, I like Mr bean's character design (funny, weird, but not violence) at first sight, but don't find Mr bean attractive.

Comment: @Hh810674 you should interpret it based on the context. I am not sure if you can find a fixed English equivalent for it. Another example, 他观众缘很差 can be "*he has no luck to gain the favor of his audience.*" Again, the interpretation is pretty variable. It all relies on the context.

Comment: @Hh810674, Can you put your example into a Chinese sentence? "*I like Mr bean's character design (funny, weird, but not violence) at first sight, but don't find Mr bean attractive*"

Comment: 我觉得他有种天生的观众缘，hope this helps to clarify the context

Comment: @Hh810674: Think about what a person really wants to convey when he says 我觉得他有种天生的观众缘. I might picture: 他是那种能够很容易吸引别人眼球的，这中特质是他与生俱来的。 So, with that in mind, I would interpret 我觉得他有种天生的观众缘 as "*I think he has sort of an inborn ability to attract the interest of the audience.*"

Comment: @dan 'attractive' strongly connotes physical attractiveness, "good looking". So I would suggest editing the first example to "audiences love her" or "she is good with an audience". Second sentence again strongly suggests physical attraction, after seeing your comments above I'd go with "He is good with people". In the 3rd sentence 'to gain' needs to be 'gaining' or 'in gaining', but really 'luck' (implying fortune) is probably not what you're after, and 'gain the favor' is strikingly formal. Maybe "He just can't connect with an audience". (?) Hope this is the kind of comment you wanted :-)

Comment: @steveLangsford yeah, thank you very much!